# Severity prediction using Random Forest Classifier wont show

Tags: python, data-science, random-forest

I am using Random forest Classifier to predict the severity of Fusarium wilt using 7 in 1 soil sensor. For my project i am using Raspi 4 and Arduino (to easily communicate sensor). In my problem now, it says in the serial monitor of pycharm (for python)

An error occurred during prediction: The feature names should match those that were passed during fit.
Feature names must be in the same order as they were in fit.

An error occurred: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

this is my code for train model for Random forest classifier and its example data set

```
import pandas as pd
import joblib
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, accuracy_score

# Load your dataset (replace 'your_dataset.csv' with the actual file path)
data = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')

# Split the dataset into features (X) and target variable (y)
X = data.drop('Severity', axis=1)  # Features (Moisture, pH, etc.)
y = data['Severity']  # Target variable (High, Moderate, Low)

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Create and train a Random Forest Classifier
rf_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)
rf_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Make predictions on the test set
y_pred = rf_classifier.predict(X_test)

# Evaluate the model's performance
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
report = classification_report(y_test, y_pred)

print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy}")
print("Classification Report:")
print(report)

joblib.dump(rf_classifier, 'trained_model.pkl')
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z-DiANZnE5UEn4oyqlXM99-2GOSaZOIM/view?usp=sharing (this is for data set file)

for reading the sensor data from arduino

```
import serial
import time
from predict_severity import predict_soil_severity

# Initialize sensor data dictionary with initial values
sensor_data = {
    'Moisture': 0.0,
    'Electrical Conductivity': 0.0,
    'pH': 0.0,
    'Nitrogen': 0.0,
    'Phosphorus': 0.0,
    'Potassium': 0.0
}

ser = serial.Serial('COM7', 9600, timeout=1.0)
time.sleep(3)
ser.reset_input_buffer()
print("Serial Ok")

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.01)
        if ser.in_waiting > 0:
            line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
            if line.startswith("Moisture: "):
                sensor_data['Moisture'] = float(line.split(": ")[1])

            if line.startswith("Soil Temperature: "):
                avg_temperature = float(line.split(": ")[1])
                formatted_avg_temperature = format(avg_temperature, ".2f")
                #print(f"Average Temperature: {formatted_avg_temperature}")

            if line.startswith("EC: "):
                sensor_data['Electrical Conductivity'] = float(line.split(": ")[1])

            if line.startswith("pH: "):
                sensor_data['pH'] = float(line.split(": ")[1])

            if line.startswith("Nitrogen: "):
                sensor_data['Nitrogen'] = float(line.split(": ")[1])

            if line.startswith("Phosphorus: "):
                sensor_data['Phosphorus'] = float(line.split(": ")[1])

            if line.startswith("Potassium: "):
                sensor_data['Potassium'] = float(line.split(": ")[1])

            if all(value != 0.0 for value in sensor_data.values()):
                # All sensor values are available and not equal to the initial values, predict severity
                severity_prediction = predict_soil_severity(sensor_data)

                # Get the class label with the highest probability
                predicted_severity = max(severity_prediction, key=lambda item: severity_prediction[item])

                print(f"Predicted Soil Severity: {predicted_severity}")

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Close Serial Comm.")
    ser.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    ser.close()
```

for predicting the severity

```
import joblib
import pandas as pd

# Load the trained model
rf_classifier = joblib.load('trained_model.pkl')

def predict_soil_severity(sensor_data):
    try:
        # Create a DataFrame from the sensor_data dictionary
        sensor_df = pd.DataFrame(sensor_data, index=[0])

        # Make predictions using the trained Random Forest Classifier
        severity_prediction = rf_classifier.predict(sensor_df)



        return severity_prediction[0]  # Return the predicted severity
    except Exception as e:
        # Handle any exceptions gracefully and log errors
        print(f"An error occurred during prediction: {e}")
        return None  # Return None to indicate an error

# Example usage (uncomment and customize as needed):
# if __name__ == "__main__":
#     sample_sensor_data = {
#         'Moisture': 0.5,
#         'Electrical Conductivity': 1.0,
#         'pH': 6.0,
#         'Nitrogen': 10.0,
#         'Phosphorus': 20.0,
#         'Potassium': 30.0
#     }
#     predicted_severity = predict_soil_severity(sample_sensor_data)
#     if predicted_severity is not None:
#         print(f"Predicted Soil Severity: {predicted_severity}")
```

in running the read data sensor it says:
An error occurred during prediction: The feature names should match those that were passed during fit.
Feature names must be in the same order as they were in fit.

An error occurred: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Can someone enlighten me, thank you